# Special event for @Input properties

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I know if all my `@Input` properties in component are already initialized with data? Is there some kind of `event`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What component? Event on where? The Browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At `ngOnInit` phase, your inputs are already have their values, which you have passed to them. There is no event to check if you pass something to them or not. You need just to check to the default values if you will not pass default values to them.